# attr is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

The following code this not work, because attr is undefined:

```
$("#foo a[href]").each(function()
{
    this.attr("href", "www.google.com");
});
```

But this code does:

```
$("#foo a[href]").each(function()
{
    this.href = "www.google.com";
});
```

Why??

Comment: Fyi, a link to `www.google.com` will not do what you want. You **need** `http://` in front of it. Unless you have a file named `www.google.com` in the same folder as your html file of course ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap `this` ... `$(this)`

`attr` is a method of a jQuery object, `href` is a property of an element node

Answer (score 3):

The `this` reference in your function is a reference to a DOM element. The reference **is not** a jQuery object.

Comment: by the way I always wondered why it was not implemented to be wrapped by default. Since in 90% of cases people do $(this), and relatively rare they need DOM element itself.

Comment: @shabuc I use it a lot for this.id, this.href, etc. Less typing, same end result, and it was the way I used to do it before the js libs.

Answer (score 2):

Because `this` inside an each refers to the DOM element itself rather than the jQuery version of it, and the `attr` method is only defined on the jQuery object.

So, to use the `attr` method you need to wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object:

```
$("#foo a[href]").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("href", "www.google.com");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try .prop()

```
this.prop("href", "www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#foo a[href]").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("href", "www.google.com");
});
```

You need the $()

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this instead?

`$(this).attr("href","www.google.com");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` isn't a jQuery object.

Try:

```
$("#foo a[href]").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "www.google.com");
});
```