# Accessing attributes (attr) of a Raphael element when triggering a mouseover event

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to access and update certain attributes of an element in a Raphael canvas when the mouseover and mouseout events trigger..

Since the documentation is sparse, I have been struggling with this for a while.

The following code fails with an error of **`Object #<SVGCircleElement> has no method 'attr'`**

```
        $(circle.node).mouseover(function (e) {
            e.target.attr({ 'opacity': 0.2, 'fill': 'blue', 'stroke': 'white' });
        });
```

The (non) functioning code is available here:  http://jsfiddle.net/agarcian/mDnAb/3/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `e.target` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. It's similar to `this`. If you want to use jQuery methods you have to pass it to jQuery first.

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [attr is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845087/attr-is-undefined)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Luckily doing this is not as bad as the other way round ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$(e.target).attr(...)` since `e.target` is a plain DOM element and not jQuery-wrapped yet.

With this change it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/mDnAb/4/

Btw, you can use `.hover()` instead of the two separate events: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/mDnAb/5/

Comment: Awesome.   This is exactly what I was looking for.    Documentation is very sparse as I said...   Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @agarcian: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) says that it is a DOM element: *The DOM element that initiated the event.*.